# Передача значения из textBox в метод другого класса, C#

Tags: c#, winforms, методы

Я хочу передать значение из текстбокса в метод стороннего класса, где их значения будут использоваться в вычислениях. У меня есть абстрактный(если это на что-то влияет) класс Figure, у которого есть наследуемый класс Rectangle, в который я и хотел передать значение с помощью такого метода внутри Form1.

```
public TextBox GetFromTextBox (TextBox TB)
{
return TB;
}
```

Но записывая в методе класса Rectangle `Form1.GetFromTextBox(textBox6)` IDE подчеркнула мне `textBox6` и заявила об отсутствии контекста.

У меня порядка восьми текстбоксов, поэтому писать под каждый текстбокс уникальный метод будет не очень. Кто-нибудь сможет объяснить, как в таких случаях стоит поступить?

Comment: 1. Почему класс Rectangle имеет доступ к форме (и имеет ли)? 2. Почему обработчики TextBox'ов не могут вызывать метод, который будет извлекать их значения и передавать в Rectangle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Должно сработать с поиском текстбокса по имени, если я правильно понял суть вопроса.

```cs
public string GetFromTextBox(string tbName)
{
    TextBox textBox = this.Controls.Find(tbName, true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
    return textBox?.Text ?? "";
}
```

И вот такой вызов

```cs
string text = GetFromTextBox("textBox6");
```